# Meteor [RangeError: Out of memory] exited with code: 3

Tags: memory, meteor

I'm running a meteor app that connects to a SQL and Mongo database. When I start the app I get this error after successfully connecting to MSSQL. I don't know if the error is related to Kadira or not but here's what happens:

Every once in awhile the app will successfully run, only to exit and restart randomly after I see the out of memory error.

I also see sometimes:

```
C:\Users...\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\packages\meteorhacks_kadira.js:3130
originalRun.call(this,val);
            ^

RangeError: Out of memory
   at Fibers.run (packages/meteorhacks:kadira/.../async.js:25:1)
    at Object._onImmediate (pakages/meteor/fiber_helpers.js:126:1)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:354:15)
```

Does this mean my computer doesn't have enough RAM to run my application? I'm not sure how to figure out the source of this error further but I was wondering if anyone has even encountered something like this? I don't think that this should be happening because others run the application without this error.

Comment: I ran into a similar OOM problem before, although it is not exactly related to kadira. Try using `sudo rm .meteor/local/; meteor reset`

Comment: any further update regarding this issue?

Comment: so I deleted the meteor local and reset, and the app worked for a bit, but the error came back. I've more or less given up on trying to run my app on my machine since I don't get this on Mac but on my windows machine only.